# Zend Layout Double Div

Tags: zend-framework, zend-layout

Hi i want to put two div in a zend view. After i want to have the two div in different position. My problem is that i want to have the normal content adn i want to add another div that rapresent the side menu
For example my view is:

```
<div id="view-menuscritte"> 
List menu   
</div>
<div id="view-content">
<?php
    echo $this->errorMessage;
    echo $this->form;
?>
</div>
```

When I use in my layout

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <img id="menusopra" src=<?php echo $this->baseUrl().'/img/menusopra.jpg'; ?> >
    <div id="menuscrittegenerale">
        <?php echo $this->layout()->menuscritte; ?>
    </div>  
    <img id="menusotto" src=<?php echo $this->baseUrl().'/img/menusotto.jpg'; ?> 
</div>  

<div id="contentgenerale">
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</div>
```

The problem is that the two div (->content and ->menuscritte) are in the same div.
view-menuscritte is not in menuscrittegenerale where it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside folder of layout.phtml , create menu.phtml 
cut and paste following content from your view into menu.phtml

```
<div id="view-menuscritte"> 
List menu   
</div>
```

Now in your layout.phtml replace

```
 <?php echo $this->layout()->menuscritte; ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $this->partial('menu.phtml);?>
```